# Proper semantic markup for utility bar, logo and main navigation in header

Tags: html, header, navigation, semantic-markup

I am trying to create an appropriate semantic markup for header section of design below.

Please header section of [this bootstrap theme](http://demo.fuviz.com/reen/v1-1/index.html) (Sorry i couldn't add image due to reputation restriction)

Please see code below

```html
<header role="banner">
  <a href="#main-content">Skip to main content</a>
  <div class="utility-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Mail</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>Number</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Social Link 1</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>Social Link 2</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>Social Link 3</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>Social Link 4</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>Social Link 5</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/logo.svg">
  </a>
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Main 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">SubMenu 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">SubMenu 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">SubMenu 3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">SubMenu 4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">SubMenu 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Main 2</li>
      <li>Main 3</li>
      <li>Main 4</li>
      <li>Main 5</li>
      <li>Main 6</li>
    </ul>
    <button title="Show / Hide menu">
      <img src="burger.png" alt="Show / Hide menu">
    </button>
  </nav>
</header>
```

From reading articles about semantics in sites like HTML5Doctor and posts in stackoverflow. I have the following doubts.

1. Where should we place the "utility bar"/ "Top Bar", which contains
   the social links and contact details? Should we place it in aside
   outside the header tag, as it is tangential content to the site.
2. Is the trick of using H1 for logo with text-indent, not advised
   anymore?
3. Where should we place the burger icon for responsive view. Some doesn't place it in the markup , but add it using javascript. It is the recommended way. if we place it in markup, where is the appropriate place.

Comment: 1. In a `<footer>`. 2. Not a semantics question. 3. Where-ever it works.

Comment: 2. is a semantics question as he is asking whether or not to include the text content and shoot if off the page, or not to include it at all

Comment: Thanks Alohci and Albert for the comments. 1. So are you suggesting to put the utility/top bar in the footer and position it on top using position absolute? . If you look at the link provided, you can see the bar it placed on top of the document. 2. Please see link [link] (http://csswizardry.com/2010/10/your-logo-is-an-image-not-a-h1/). So i just want to make sure with experts. Since this is a common header pattern these days, i wanted to check, whether there is a accepted semantic markup for this.

Comment: You can put a footer at the top if you like. A footer element is *semantically* a footer, it says nothing about its placement.